# How to "Mark as Read" an Email in Gmail using Gmail API?

Tags: php, gmail-api

I have used Gmail API for reading Mails and it's working fine. I was successfully able to do that. But as I want that particular email as "Mark as Read" (**Note**: "Mark as Read" not apply the label here) whenever I read that email through Gmail API, I was unable to do so. Actually, I didn't find any method to do so through Gmail API. Is there any way to do so?

PS: I'm using PHP for this process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to [modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify#try-it) the message, and remove the `UNREAD` label.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/{MESSAGE_ID}/modify?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}

{
 "removeLabelIds": [
  "UNREAD"
 ]
}
```

Using the Gmail API PHP client you could do something like the following:

```
$mods = new Google_Service_Gmail_ModifyMessageRequest();
$mods->setRemoveLabelIds(array("UNREAD"));
$message = $service->users_messages->modify($userId, $messageId, $mods);
```

Comment: Thanks. You also need gmail.modify scope GMAIL_MODIFY